# Regex - remove text while replacing text with c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am attempting to learn regex by using it to edit some scripts I have.

My scripts contain  like so

```
<person name="John">Will be out of town</person><person name="Julie">Will be in town.</person>
```

I need to replace the name values in the script - the addition to the name is always the same, but I might have names that I don't want to update.

Quick example of what I have:

```
string[] names = new string[1];
names[0] = "John-Example";
names[1] = "Paul-Example";

string ToFix = "<person name=\"John\">Will be out of town</person><person name=\"Julie\">Will be in town.</person>"

for (int i=0; i<names.Length; i++)
{
    string Name = names[i];
    ToFix = Regex.Replace(ToFix, "(<.*name=\")(" + Name.Replace("-Example", "") + ".*)(\".*>)", "$1" + Name + "$3", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

This works for the most part, but I have two problems with it.  Sometime it removes too much, if I have multiple persons in the string, it will remove everything between the first person and the last person, as so:

```
Hello <person name="John">This is John</person><person name="Paul">This is Paul</person>
```

becomes

```
Hello <person name="John-Example">This is Paul</person>
```

Also, I would like to remove any extra text behind the name value and before the closing carrat, so that:

```
<person name="John" hello>
```

Should be corrected to:

```
<person name="John-Example">
```

I have read several articles on regex and feel that I am just missing something small here.  How and why would I go about fixing this?

EDIT:  I don't think these scripts that I am working with classify as XML - the entire script may or may not have <> tags.  Back to my original goal with this question, can someone explain the behavior of the regex?  And how would I remove extra text after the name value before the closing tag?

Comment: it's xml..you should use an xml parser.. **not** regex

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is too greedy. Try `.*?` rather than just `.*`

Also, please don't use regex to parse XML.

Here's an example of how to do what I think you want, using [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(ToFix);
foreach (var person in xdoc.Elements("person"))
{
    var name = person.Attribute("name");
    if (person.LastAttribute != name)
    {
        person.RemoveAttributes();
        person.SetAttributeValue(name.Name, name.Value + "-Example");
    }
}
var output = xdoc.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  These examples are generally the size of my scripts, what would be an better alternative to regex?

Comment: I've added an example. You should probably google something like "c# parse xml"